# maximize $x^\top A x^\top$ subject to $\|x \| = 1$ and $ \langle x, v_1 \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix.

Firstly, consider the optimization problem:
$$
maximize \ x^\top A x^\top \ subject \ to \ \| x\| = 1
$$

The optimization problem admits a solution denote by $v_1$. Here I know that $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$, since by Lagrange multipliers, $\nabla f = Ax+(x^\top A)^\top = Ax+A^\top x = 2Ax = \lambda \nabla g = \lambda 2x$, since $v_1$ is a solution to the optimization problem, $Av_1= \lambda v_1$.

Now consider this:
$$
maximize \ x^\top A x^\top \ subject \ to 、 \| x \| = 1 \ and \ \langle x, v_1 \rangle =0
$$
Let $v_2$ be the solution of this problem. How to show that $v_2$ is an eigenvector of $A$ that is orthogonal to $v_1$?

Comment: I assume you meant $x\perp v_1$? Have you seen Lagrange multipliers with multiple constraints?

Comment: I fixed it. Yes but I stll don't know how to show $v1 \perp v2$

Comment: Your conditions for $v_2$ is that $x=v_2$ maximizes a function subject to two constraints, one of which is  $\langle x,v_1 \rangle =0$, i.e., $v_2\perp v_1$. The bigger question is why it's actually an eigenvector.

Comment: Well, you have a symmetric matrix and hence an orthonormal set of vectors, if you use Lagrange multipliers again you will get the eigenvector with the second biggest eigenvalue. Orthogonality is an imposed constraint when you construct the Lagrange function

Comment: Let $V_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the orthogonal complement to the eigenvector $v_1$, so that $\mathbb{R}^n = V_1 \oplus \mathbb{R} v_1$. The matrix $A$ is block-diagonal along this decomposition, and one such block is $A_1 \colon V_1 \to V_1$, a symmetric linear operator on $V_1$. The second minimisation problem you have is just the first minimisation problem, applied to $V_1$ and $A_1$ rather than to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x^TAx$, $g_1(x)=x^Tx-1$, $g_2(x)=x^Tv_1$. Lagrange multipliers says that to maximize $f(x)$ subject to $g_1(x)=g_2(x)=0$, we need to solve
$$\nabla f(x)=\lambda \nabla g_1(x)+\mu \nabla g_2(x)$$
together with $g_1(x)=g_2(x)=0$.

Explicitly,

$$2Ax=2\lambda x + \mu v_1, \langle x,x \rangle =1, \langle x,v_1 \rangle=0$$

If we take the first equation and take the inner product with $v_1$ and use the two constraints, we get $2\langle v_1,Ax \rangle = 2\lambda \langle v_1,x \rangle + \mu \langle v_1, v_1 \rangle$, which becomes $0=\mu$.  Going back to the original equation, we get

$$Ax=\lambda x.$$

So the $x$ which maximizes subject to the constraints is an eigenvector.

Comment: Sorry, may I ask why you let $g_1(x)=x^Tx-1$? I think $g_1(x)=||x||-1$, so $g_1(x)=\sqrt{x^Tx}-1$?

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll Because those two equations have exactly the same zero sets, but my choice has a significantly nicer derivative. It is a common trick to work with the square of a norm instead of the norm itself when working with norms defined by inner products (generalizations of Euclidean distance).